# Void* pointer problem

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Pretty new to c++, i have a rather (i think) stupid question about a piece of code :

```
class DataStream
{
protected:
 DataStream(void) { };
public:
 DataStream(int Length); 
 ~DataStream(void);

...
 void* DataPtr;
 int Length;
};
```

I do have a class similiar to this and i want to assign to DataPtr a pointer to some data allocated.
When i do

```
DataStream::DataStream(int length)
{
char* arr = new char[length];
this->DataPtr = arr;
this->Length = length;
}
```

All i get is corrupting the class (the length variable assume strange values) and the dataptr is not the same as the arr pointer.
Why is that?
What am i missing?

EDIT for information :

Windows Platform, 
Visual Studio 2010, 
The implementation is just that (done in the constructor).
The including class is a simple EMPTY class with only a constructor that calls in return the constructor of the DataStream class. The class name is ShaderFormat.
In the main app the only lines are

```
ShaderFormat* sf = new ShaderFormat();
DataStream* ds = sf->Save();
```

I was not directly referencing DataStream in the main app, only the shaderformat classes. (that was the problem it seems)
Why is that?

Comment: Here your code looks alright, can you post your entire code? Because the issue may be arising out of some other issue.

Comment: I'm assuming the Length argument passed into the constructor is set to both the Length (big "L") member and a length (little "L") local variable?

Comment: yeah its just a typo, the code is pretty much only that one.
The only thing that its inside a library (.lib)

Comment: I added the header to the project linking to the lib (i was only adding the containing class instead of the datastream one) and suddently its working. what's the reason behind it? :|

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Don't use `void` to denote an empty function parameter list. This is a C-ism that is not proper C++ (your compiler may support it as an extension, to allow you to compile C code). Simply write empty parentheses: `fun()`

Comment: To me it sounds like something else is stomping memory being used by your DataStream objects. Without posting more of your code, this will be really difficult for us to debug. Have you tried setting a data breakpoint on one of the DataPtrs that is getting overwritten?

Comment: @slacker: `void` is non-standard? I don't think it *has* to be empty.

Comment: @GMan:
Yup. It does not exist in C++, and is retained in C99 only for the sake of backwards compatibility. The right and future-proof way to declare a function with zero parameters - in both C++ *and C99* is to use empty parentheses

Comment: @slacker: I think you're incorrect. Where did you get that information? In both the C++03 and C++0x-FCD, 8.3.5 explicitly state: "The parameter list (void) is equivalent to the empty parameter list." That's hardly the same as declaring it deprecated, nor does it make it a compiler extension to support it. In fact, a compiler that didn't accept `(void)` and treat it as `()` would be non-compliant!

Answer (score 2):

When managing dynamic resources like that in a class, remember the [**rule of three**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). You need:

- **copy constructor** to make a copy (or increment a reference count) of the resource,
- **copy assignment operator** - same,
- **destructor** to release the resource if not referenced anymore.

Number of tools is available to ease this management:

- Plain `std::vector<char>` as member of your class can probably solve your particular array problem - it manages memory for you and gives you control over length of the buffer, and it *is* fully copyable.
- Privately inheriting from [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) disables all copy semantics. This might be suitable for non-sharable resources.
- [Boost Smart Pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) library provides set of classes with *scoped* and *reference-counted* semantics for managing pointers and arrays.

Getting deeper into C++ development you will find that you work less with bold pointers and more with tiny wrapper classes and references.

Comment: Seriously, the first step to solving problems is to get rid of the areas where bad things can happen. No reason to be using pointers like in OP's code. +1

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to shrink your example to a complete yet small one exhibiting the behavior?  I see no reason that assignment would affect other members of the object .

Comment: This should be a comment and not a reply.

Comment: i've tried in an isolate environment and the problem does not appear.
I've tried to strip down everything. the problem appear on one project, and not on the another. (i use the same code...and there is no additional executed code in either project)

Comment: the only difference i can see its that in one case the class is inside in a lib and in the second case its directly in the app...it can make a differnece?

Answer (score 0):

what about casting arr to void* and when you need it casting it to char* ?